# how to add data to xml file dynamically

Tags: android

hi i am new to android.What i did is i am creating a xml file with some data.Now i need to add some additional data to existing xml file dynamically.How can i done this.Pls help me.Thank u in advance.

Comment: You have to specify your question. Do you want to generate a XML structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that you do with XML in your layout file can be done via coding inside the `.java` files.

For example, if you want to change the text of the label, you grad the ressource in your code and modify it or if you have a table and want to add data depening on some previous operations, you create the rows programmatically and add it to the "xml" table.

Read through the [UI Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) to get many examples and explanations. The Dev Guide is a great ressource and well written.